# Google sign in failed after using new google-services.json

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-play-services

I'm working with google sign in form firebase authentication. I used my debug SHA1 key before and the app was working totally fine but then I changed my SHA1 key to release and changed the JSON file in my app folder too.

Now it's not working anymore, `GoogleSignInResult` returns `false` always. 
What should I do? 
Thanks!

Comment: do you use in emulator or in phone?

Comment: in my phone....

Answer (score 0):

When you use the release SHA-1, you have to create/generate a release version of apk, and install it in your phone. Note that running the apps from Android Studio will always in debugging state.

It is either *keep the debug SHA-1 and continue until the apps is complete, and then after that you change the SHA-1 to a release one*, **or**, *use the release SHA-1, every time want to try out or use the Google Sign-In, generate the release apk and copy it into your phone*.

UPDATE:

If both doesn't work, probably need to check the JSON.